# Error: could not find or load main class (another one)

Tags: java, shell

I've searched throughout this site and tried a few solutions when receiving this message but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to invoke a shell script on Ubuntu 12.04.2 (with java-7-openjdk-amd64) that runs a java program and then I get a "Error: Could not find or load main class com.xx" error.

This is how my script invokes Java:

```
"$JAVA" $server_jvmargs $javaProps -Dxx.home="$XX_HOME" -Duser.dir="$XX_HOME" -cp $client_classpath $mainclass $args
```

And the arguments you see above are defined as follows:

```
args=$*
javaProps=
mainclass=com.xx
server_jvmargs="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m $jvmargs"
XX_HOME="`pwd`/../.."
client_classpath="$XX_HOME/lib/client/patch.jar;$XX_HOME/lib/client/xyx-xxx.jar;$clientlibs;$XX_HOME/lib/server/standard-1.1.2.jar;$publictilesource;$respath;$XX_HOME/lib/client/xxmainclass.jar"
```

The mainclass variable is in the classpath located in the xxmainclass.jar file so I'm not sure as to why it cannot find it?

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: Is you class name `com.xx`? This looks more like the name of the package. Also, make sure the class has a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: My class name isn't com.xx exactly but the reference is to the class, the class is packaged in a jar file. Essentially this was working in a Windows batch file, but I've been trying to convert it to a Linux shell file.

Comment: The `mainclass` parameter should be the complete name of the class then.

Comment: I've just changed it to the class name and it comes up with the same error (albeit with a different class name)

Comment: FYI, `args=$*` is badly buggy. If you want to be able to preserve an argument list with IFS characters (such as spaces) or glob characters that match files in the local directory, you need to use bash arrays, not string variables, and `"$@"` rather than `$*`. Not the immediate cause of the bug you asked about, but it's _a_ bug you should be aware of.

Comment: ...actually, this script is _full_ of places where string-splitting is used to form argument lists. It's somewhat endemic in scripts that start Java programs (I'm guessing they crib off each other?), but consistently hazardous (if you want to pass in a Java property containing whitespace in its value, or a path to a jar located in a directory with whitespace in its filename... good luck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what *actually* happens when you run your script, invoke it with `bash -x`, or put `set -x` at the top; this will print each command before it's run, so you can see how it's *actually* starting the JVM. Without this information, it's hard to come up with a better diagnosis. That said...

---

You've been copying off Tomcat's startup scripts, it looks like. Don't; they're awful.

Something a little more correct on the shell side might look like this:

```
args=( "$@" )
javaProps=( )
mainclass=com.xx
server_jvmargs=( -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m "${jvmargs[@]}" )
XX_HOME="$PWD/../.."
client_classpath="$XX_HOME/lib/client/patch.jar:$XX_HOME/lib/client/xyx-xxx.jar:$clientlibs:$XX_HOME/lib/server/standard-1.1.2.jar:$publictilesource:$respath:$XX_HOME/lib/client/xxmainclass.jar"

java \
  "${server_jvmargs[@]}" \
  "${javaProps[@]}" \
  -Dxx.home="$XX_HOME" \
  -Duser.dir="$XX_HOME" \
  -cp "$client_classpath" \
  "$mainclass" "${args[@]}"
```

The use of `${foo[@]}` expands the array `foo` with literal contents. Note that `foo` must be *created* as an array in this case, and you need to be using a shell that supports arrays (so your script needs to start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`).

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 for an introduction to arrays in bash.

Comment: Tomcat's startup scripts? I was using http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html to convert an existing batch script to a shell script.

I have been able to rectify the problem now thanks to your help. The XX_HOME was incorrect. I was using a script to call a configuration script in a sub-directory, but I guess I haven't called it correctly as when the configuration script calls $PWD it does the path of the initial script rather than the config script.

Comment: A big thanks though. Would you say that the wiki link you provided be a good reference to look at for code style?

Comment: @mafyou To quote greybot from irc.freenode.org's #bash channel: The infamous "Advanced" Bash Scripting Guide should be avoided unless you know how to filter out the junk. It will teach you to write bugs, not scripts. In that light, the BashGuide was written: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 1):

use a : instead of a ; in your classpath.

unix just rolls that way.

Comment: I've replaced them, but am getting the same error unfortunately. Is there a specific syntax for it? Eg. I got caught up when I didn't have a space in my `[]` for if statements...

Comment: try charles suggestion/. does it work if you type everything in manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Java -jar pathToYOurFile.jar

Comment: That only invokes the class hardcoded in the manifest, whereas what they're trying to do invokes a class they name themselves. Very different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if line end character is OS specific in your shell script

Comment: you can post such queries under comments. Answer section is for solutions.